# in the direction of

Tags: prepositions

For the image below is this sentence correct?
Feet of 'B' are in the direction of A's head.
If not, how would we describe this? We have to mention B's feet and A's head in the sentence.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I think that would do. Although these options would sound a bit more smooth for me:

- The feet of 'B' are towards A's head.
- The feet of 'B' point towards A's head.
- B's feet point in the direction of A's head.

Also, using *are pointing* instead of *point* would be correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think that talking about the direction of the feet alone sounds a bit odd. I would prefer, "B is lying with their feet towards A's head".

Or, if you *literally* need "B's feet" then something like, "B's feet are positioned towards A's head" or "B's feet are close to A's head."